# ¿Cómo ocultar "Imagen en imagen" en los controles de un vídeo?

Tags: html

Tengo un vídeo. Si pulso en los tres botones pequeños que hay en la esquina inferior derecha, aparecería "Descargar" e "Imagen en imagen". Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo desaparecer ambas cosas, o por así decirlo, que los tres puntos no se vean?

```html
<video width="300" height="150" controls src="#"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que agregar el atributo [`controlsList="nodownload"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Attributes) y `disablePictureInPicture` (*ambas son experimental, lo que significa que [no funcionan en todos los navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#search=controlsList).*)

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<video width="300" height="150" src="#" controls disablePictureInPicture controlsList="nodownload"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes de añadir el atributo controlsList & disablePicture

```html
<video width="300" height="150" src="#" controls disablePictureInPicture controlsList="nodownload"></video>
```